# Scala/Play Framework: How to modify fields in Form object before validation

Tags: forms, scala, validation, playframework, playframework-2.0

One of the simples things in a web app should be to read fields from HTML forms. The play framework offers the Form class to validate and map those answers. It works fine as long as you don't want to do special things.

I found out that with

```
   val newform = user.copy(errors = user.errors++Seq(FormError("email", "Already registered")), data = user.data + ("username"->"correctedName")
```

I can modify errors and fields before redisplaying the form.

But how is it possible to modify fields **before** they get validated?
It would be nice to remove unwanted white spaces, transform "11.05.2014" into "11-May-2014" and such things.

Comment: You could write a custom body parser for your specific form

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might be able to do it within the `Form` object if you make your validation rules more lax (`nonEmptyText` instead of `email` for an email with unwanted whitespace), use `transform` to clean up the input, then `verifying` to implement the actual validation rule. That would probably end up being very ugly, so I won't continue following that path.

I think you're only good option may be passing the form data through a filter before calling `bindFromRequest`. Assuming you're using the `parse.urlFormEncoded` `BodyParser` (which you should be), then `request.data` is a `Map[String, Seq[String]]`.

This a crude example of a filter, but anything that will accept a `Map[String, Seq[String]]`, and return a new `Map[String, Seq[String]]` with cleansed data.

```
def cleanUserForm(data: Map[String, Seq[String]]): Map[String, Seq[String]] = {
    data.map{ case (key, values) =>
        if(key == "email") (key, values.map(_.replaceAll(" ", ""))) // trim whitespace from email
        else (key, values)
    }
}
```

Then in your controller, you'd have to explicitly pass the cleansed data to `bindFromRequest` (which normally accepts an implicit request):

```
def register = Action(parse.urlFormEncoded) { request =>
    val incomingData = request.body
    val cleanData = cleanUserForm(incomingData)
    userForm.bindFromRequest(cleanData).fold(
        formWithErrors => ...
        user => ...
    )
}

val userForm: Form[User] = Form {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Your solution is working. But I'm asking myself if Scalas immutable are a performance break, when you need to copy information all the time instead of only updating those fields that need an update. Copying a complete input structure seems absolute overkill to me. Can a programming language really be good if you need to do pull-ups to do such simple things. Maybe Java without immutables would be a better choice.

Comment: There's a trade-off. With immutable data structures you get safer and more legible code (among other things), but there's a performance hit at times. Still, the overhead of copying a small `Map` is negligible. And even if you have a thousand fields (arbitrary choice of size), you can still fall back to mutable collections to optimize. In any case, the solution for your problem is needed not because of the Scala language, but the design of Play. This isn't necessarily a "simple" thing.

Comment: This solution worked for me as well.  I just wanted to add that if you only intend to trim whitespace from the beginning/end of a string, you can use the `String.trim` function in Scala.